# How do I schedule a PHP program to run in intervals as scheduled on the server?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a MySQL table in my database that holds email addresses and payment amounts. I am trying to schedule a job that would read from the table according to certain criteria set in the SQL and send the email addresses and payment amounts to Paypal using MassPay API using the Name Value Pair interface for payouts.

I know that CRON jobs can serve the purpose but really have no idea about how to go about creating one.

The main code that will create the Interface Data will be PHP.

Any help or insight on how to go about doing this is much appreciated.

Comment: Check this out on how to create a cron job in a shared hosting: http://www.upstartblogger.com/how-to-create-a-cron-job-in-cpanel

Comment: Excellent tutorial link. Thanks @ign. I will try this and post here how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `crontab -e` to edit the cron table.

To create an entry: http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

In the case of GoDaddy: http://help.godaddy.com/topic/67/article/3547

Comment: Thanks @stillstanding. Since I am on GoDaddy the help topic link is all I needed. Its really easy to create a CRON job following this link.

Answer (score 8):

A [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job **is** the easiest way to go about it. Nothing prevents you from executing PHP code from a cron job. You just write your PHP script and ask cron to execute it at your preferred interval.

Comment: I am on a Shared Linux hosting. If I have the PHP script in root, how do I go about configuring the CRON job / crontab in my GoDaddy domain.

Comment: @Aakash you should be able to configure a cron job from your GoDaddy control panel. As far as I can see cron jobs have been supported on shared hosting on GoDaddy since 2007.

Comment: Thanks man. I will try some of the tutorial links posted here and see how it goes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Run `crontab -e`, and it will open up an editor with that user's cron file.

The line you need to add will be something like this:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/php/script.php
```

This example would run the script at 3 a.m. every day, the first 5 fields are:
Minute, Hour, DayOfMonth, Month, DayOfWeek.
The values can be wildcarded (*) to run every minute, an actual number, or something like */15 to run every 15 minutes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples

Comment: Thanks for the examples link. I will try it out.